# diff command + cygwin + how to read the output

Tags: bash, shell

I am tring to understand how to use the `diff` command to undersand the difference between these files. Can someone please explain what this means?   `cases.sh` was written in notepad++, `cases2.sh` was written in nano from within cygwin on windows7. but I cannot see the difference as I don't think it is visible? what is the advice for getting cases.sh to work, but I want to understand what is wrong with it.

```
$ diff cases.sh cases2.sh
1,13c1,13
< #!/bin/sh
< # Prompt user to enter a character
< echo "Please enter a letter:"
< read charac
< case $charac in
<       "a"|"A") echo "You have typed a vowel!" ;;
<       "e"|"E") echo "You have typed a vowel!" ;;
<       "i"|"I") echo "You have typed a vowel!" ;;
<       "o"|"O") echo "You have typed a vowel!" ;;
<       "u"|"U") echo "You have typed a vowel!" ;;
<       *)         echo "You have typed a consonant!" ;;
< esac
< exit 0
\ No newline at end of file
---
> #!/bin/sh
> # Prompt user to enter a character
> echo "Please enter a letter:"
> read charac
> case $charac in
>       "a"|"A") echo "You have typed a vowel!" ;;
>       "e"|"E") echo "You have typed a vowel!" ;;
>       "i"|"I") echo "You have typed a vowel!" ;;
>       "o"|"O") echo "You have typed a vowel!" ;;
>       "u"|"U") echo "You have typed a vowel!" ;;
>       *)         echo "You have typed a consonant!" ;;
> esac
> exit 0
```

`cases.sh` does not work, I wrote this in notepad++ and I get the error below

```
$ ./cases.sh
Please enter a letter:
t
': not a valid identifier `charac
./cases.sh: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `$'in\r''
'/cases.sh: line 5: `case $charac in
```

`cases2.sh` does work but I wrote this in nano from within cygwin on windows7

```
$ ./cases2.sh
Please enter a letter:
t
You have typed a consonant!
```

Answer (score 1):

try turning on "show all characters" in notepad++ ... sounds like you have windows-style newlines set for your default editor settings there. Convert the file to unix-style newlines and try running it.

Answer (score 0):

You're encountering the classic linefeed problem.

Linux and the Unices (including compatibility layers like Cygwin) use a single `\n` (newline) to terminate each line, while the Windows family uses `\r\n` (carriage return, newline) for each line.

As a result, many (although not all) Unix utilities will choke on scripts written on Windows, as they contain additional, invisible, carriage returns. In your case, `diff` *knows* that `cases1.sh` differs from `cases2.sh` on those lines, but doesn't display the `\r` characters that actually cause the difference. Similarly, `bash` gets caught up on the carriage returns.

The easiest solution is enable Unix line endings in your editor of choice, and to run a tool like `dos2unix` on the scripts you've already written. It should be available in Cygwin's repositories.